# Like document.getElementById("id") in javascript, what we can do in angular2 and above versions to get dom element in type script

Tags: angular

Like document.getElementById("id") in javascript, what we can do in angular2 and above versions to get dom element in type script?

I tried with angular.element but its not working

Comment: You can use `ViewChild` decorator within your component class (see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. I am going to show one of them.

1. You can use this.

   - document.querySelectorAll('.class-name')
   - document.querySelectorAll('#idname')
   - document.querySelectorAll('#tagname')

the working example is here

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8gau2

2. You can use @viewChild as well

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';


  @ViewChild('pRef', {static: false}) pRef: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML); 
    this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "DOM updated succesfully!!!"; 
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}" ></hello>

<p #pRef>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

The working example is here

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example

You can find more info about `ViewChild` and it's usage here: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

It is against Angular's guidelines to directly modify the DOM.
Instead use `ViewChild(ren)()` selector and modify the element using the `Renderer2` service.

Ex:

---

```
<div #myDiv> </div>
```

```
...
@ViewChild('myDiv',{static:true}) myDiv:ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer:Renderer2){
this.renderer.setStyle(this.myDiv.elementRef,'style','value');
}
```

Comment: Just a note, it's a bad practice also using `ViewChild` to set a style. Yes, it should be preferred over `document.querySelector`, but use it only if you need to perform expensive actions that can't be easily made in the template. If your goal is to change the style, it's better using `[style]="..."` or `[style.property]="..."` in the template

Comment: Good thing pointing this out. I was just giving a short example on how to combine the usage of `ViewChild` and `Renderer` .